# How to compute the $G$-theory groups of $k[x,y,z,w]/(xy-zw,yz-w^2,xw-z^2)$ for any field $k$

Tags: algebraic-k-theory

I am trying to compute the $G$-theory groups of the ring $R=k[x,y,z,w]/(xy-zw,yz-w^2,xw-z^2)$ for any field $k$.
This is my progress so far:
Note that $R/y$ is isomorphic to $k[x,z,w]/(zw,w^2,xw-z^2)$,so that $(R/y)_{red}$ is isomorphic to $k[x,z,w]/(z,w)$, which is isomorphic to $k[x]$.
And $R_y$ is isomorphic to $k[y,1/y,w]$.
Consider the $G$-theory localization sequence for $R$:
$...\rightarrow G_{n+1}(R_y)\rightarrow G_n(R/y)\rightarrow G_n(R)\rightarrow G_n(R_y)\rightarrow ...$
Note that this is a sequence of $K_*(k)$-module homomorphisms.
And $G_{n+1}(R_y)\cong G_{n+1}(k[y,1/y,w])$, which is isomorphic to $G_{n+1}(k)\oplus G_n(k)$,and $G_n(R/y)\cong G_n(k[x])\cong G_n(k)$.
How should I compute the boundary map $\partial:G_{n+1}(R_y)\rightarrow G_n(R/y)$?
I am stuck here.
Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: This is the so-called "twisted cubic," no? That might be a good keyword to google...

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: It is the affine cone over the twisted cubic...

Comment: Thank you for your information.

Comment: It's a cone, hence it is $\mathbb{A}^1$-contractible, no?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Is there a way to do this computation without using algebraic geometry? Thanks.

Comment: How should I compute the boundary map using algebraic K-theory?Thanks.